# ID типа UUID, как правильно прописать?

Tags: postgresql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-jpa

У меня есть сущность и я хочу чтобы она имела id в таблице типа UUID

При аннотировании поля как

```
@Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
  @Column(name = "data_id")
  private UUID id;
```

я получаю ошибку

```
 Ошибка: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unknown integral data type for ids : java.util.UUID; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: Unknown integral data type for ids : java.util.UUID
```

при вызове метода на сохранение данной сущности в контроллере

```
Data data1 = new Data(UUID.randomUUID(), другие параметры, , , );
      dataRepository.save(data1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На мой взгляд проблема в том, что hibernate не может понять, что за тип данных такой.
Для решения проблемы в частном случае необходимо задать тип колонки в явном виде, а именно

```
@Id
@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type = "pg-uuid")
private UUID id;
```

в данном случае pg-uuid является конкретным типом данных для postgres

В общем случае можно описать так:

```
import java.util.UUID;
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

/**
 * JPA Convention to automatically convert UUID from Database (PostgreSQL) into Java and vice versa.
 */
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class UuidConverter implements AttributeConverter<UUID, UUID> {

    @Override
    public UUID convertToDatabaseColumn(UUID attribute) {
        return attribute;
    }

    @Override
    public UUID convertToEntityAttribute(UUID dbData) {
        return dbData;
    }

}
```